# How can I use a variable in Twig stylesheets?

Tags: css, symfony, themes, twig

I want to load my page with different theme `CSS` files and I need a solution to inject the theme name into the `css/less` path.

```
{% block stylesheets %}

{% stylesheets
'bundles/design/css/templates/{{ theme_name }}/style.less'
output='css/compiled/template_{{ theme_name }}_style.css'
%}
<link href="{{ asset_url }}" rel="stylesheet" />
{% endstylesheets %}

{% endblock %}
```

Unfortunately neither this nor the concat syntax work. How can I do that?

EDIT: Maybe someone could give me an example or a tutorial link how can use that more comfortable in my template?

```
index.php?layout=classic&theme=blue
```

Answer (score 1):

You cant't do it, there is a closed [issue](https://github.com/kriswallsmith/assetic/issues/60) about it. [Stof](https://github.com/kriswallsmith/assetic/issues/60#issuecomment-1228612) well define because it's impossible to do.

Comment: Really? Thats an old discussion. How all the other guys solve that issue when they use themes? I really cannot believe, I have to put all style definitions in one file and decide on body css class for example.

Comment: not exactly, here you are asking to build your less in css: ```{% stylesheets
'bundles/design/css/templates/{{ theme_name }}/style.less'
output='css/compiled/template_{{ theme_name }}_style.css'
%}``` 
if you want to write this with a concat var you can: <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
      href="{{ app.request.scheme ~  '://' ~  app.request.host ~ }}/css/{{ your_var }}_template.css ">

Comment: If you have a lot of traffic on your site, it would be more efficient to have the different css files already built and switch between name using a variable, but do not compile each time a page is loaded.  You can easily use a twig variable to select the proper css file.

Comment: I want to render a lot documents with the same structure but different layout and different color themes. The base template is almost always the same. But without using variables I have to write a lot childtemplates to include the different files. Thats sounds not usefull for me.

Comment: you could define an include with all stylesheets for generation and then call only what you need in template. Another strategy is to use grunt and some NodeJS packages for less to css conversion and then add only the css link in template.